# Use regex in PHP to find a {%shortcode%} that is not yet wrapped in a div with specific class?

Tags: php, regex

I use shortcodes in my HTML content that is treated by PHP. A shortcode can be {%sometag%}. It's always wrapped in {%  and %}

I have unto now wrapped these each time I load a page by using:

```
$SOME['content'] = preg_replace('/{%(.*?)%}/is', 
"<div class=\"portlet \\1adm \" data-type=\"app\">{%\\1%}</div>", 
$SOME['content']);
```

This works well, and outputs the HTML I want. BUT it wrapps {%sometag%} every time that page is loaded. So I get a wrapper inside a wrapper inside a wrapper etc.

How can I make the regex such that is only chooses /{%(.*?)%}/is but NOT when the shorttag is wrapped in a `<div class="app" >` ?

(And the class="" can hold many classes?

**In other words:**

The regex shall choose `{%sometag%}`

but not when inside a div like this:  `<div class"portlet app someclass">{%sometag%}</div>`

I'm stuck here, and really appreciate some help.

EDIT:
Have tried this as suggested in a comment (thank you).

```
$SOME['content'] = preg_replace('~<div\s+class="portlet[^"<]*"[^<]*>{%.*?%}</div>(*SKIP)(*FA‌​IL)|{%(.*?)%}~is', 
"<div class=\"portlet \\1adm \" data-type=\"app\">{%\\1%}</div>", 
$SOME['content']);
```

This broke the PHP (blank page).

Comment: Try `'~<div\s+class="portlet[^"<]*"[^<]*>{%.*?%}</div>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{%(.*?)%}~is'`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try now :-)

Comment: It broke the PHP.

Comment: It is because you copied/pasted from the comment. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/mSDP1I/1).

Comment: What is wrong here? http://bildr.no/view/clY4UGdD I just don't see it :-)

Comment: That is an image. You cannot check the presence of unprintable chars in an image. More, unprintable chars cannot be seen at all.

Comment: That is an image of the code in my code editor. That breaks my PHP. I can not see why. It should not allow any unprintable chars. My point was just to ask if that looked right. If it does, then I'll try to rinse the code. Strange if a code editor allow unprinted chars. But it might be :-)

Comment: You copied the text from the comment. SO may add garbage chars into comments. Inside `FA‌​IL` right after `A`, there is 1-2 garbage chars.

Comment: I just cleansed it and tried. My editor actually allowed the garbage chars, and have not seen that before in my editor. However, now it doesn't break, but doesn't add the div.portlet wrapper to {%map%} for instance.

Comment: [You don't say so.](https://ideone.com/ICsbQw)

Comment: @Preben you can use my library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode with custom Syntax object and it will work perfectly. Let me know if you need any help.